# How can I be sure it's always possible to draw perpendicular lines (altitudes) inside triangles?

Tags: triangles

So, I've come across this proof for the ratio of corresponding sides of similar triangles on the [internet](https://qph.ec.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-db0c31c351fdcebef5a7adf3b1fd7cfd-c), but the proof requires that we draw a perpendicular line (an [altitude](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Altitude_(triangle))) inside the triangle.

It might seem a silly question, but how can I be sure it is always possible to draw a perpendicular line connecting one vertex of any triangle to one of its sides? In other words, how can I show that every triangle has at least one altitude which lies within the triangle? Thanks.

Comment: Can you add the image to the question? I would be happy to provide a heuristic answer.

Comment: @TheCount The proof I referred to is hyperlinked under the word "internet". It requires right at the outset that a perpendicular line be drawn connecting one vertex of the triangle to one of its sides. I just wonder whether it is always possible to draw such a line inside a triangle, regardless of the lenghts of the sides

Comment: the longest edge is always 'inside' for the perpendicular.

Comment: @NickD. I think you misunderstood. you can always draw a perpendicular inside, just not necessarily from *every* vertex.

Comment: You're right, I didn't read that carefully enough! Thanks.